# page referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord.py

I sometimes see this is in my log, but I can't figure out how sometimes `page` does not get assigned

```py
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser') 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'page' referenced before assignment`
```

```py
    async def champion(self, ctx, champion, role='default'):
        roles = ['adc', 'top', 'mid', 'jungle', 'support']     
        
        if role == 'default':
            page = requests.get(f'https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol/champions/{champion}/build')
        elif role.lower() in roles:
            page = requests.get(f'https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol/champions/{champion}/build?role={role}')
        elif role.lower() == 'aram':
            page = requests.get(f'https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol/champions/{champion}/aram-builds')
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(description="Invalid role!", color=0xfda5b0)
            embed.add_field(name='Roles', value='`top` `jungle` `mid` `adc` `support` `aram`')
            await ctx.send(embed=embed) 
            
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Try putting `return` right before the `ctx.send` in the else block

Comment: The reason this is happening is that if you hit your `else` in your if statement you do not create the `page` variable but still attempt to use the page variable after the if statement.